# OpenSSH running on Windows Server - "Permission Denied" when downloading files

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2019

running into an odd issue - we've had OpenSSH (`OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5`) running on a hosted Windows Server 2019 for over a year, and have had a programmatic process written in Python in place to connect via paramiko and SFTP a file down.

Found that it had stopped working and is throwing an `[Errno 13] Permission Denied` error. However, when using (not ideal) ftplib in place of paramiko, it downloads fine. Also tested with GUI clients (WinSCP / CyberDuck) - SFTP doesn't work - FTP does.

Pertinent (uncommented) lines from `sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
GatewayPorts no
PermitTunnel no
X11Forwarding no

Match User USERNAME 
    ChrootDirectory X:\PATH\TO\DIR
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -d X:\PATH\TO\DIR
```

But nothing had changed on here between when it was working and when it stopped. Nothing as far as the sshd_config file that is. Event Viewer isn't showing any recent OpenSSH Admin logs, and Operational logs just show `sshd: Accepted password for USERNAME from PU.BL.IC.IP port ##### ssh2`

Anything to point us in the right direction so I can remove ftplib would be much appreciated.